# Use attribute routing parameters for other attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributes, custom-attributes

I use Attribute Routing (MVC) to call Controller Methods and also an Authorizationattribute with custom Properties:

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
[UserAuth(ProjectId=3)]
public ActionResult Select(int id) {  
    return JsonGet(Magic.DoSomethingMagic());
}
```

UserAuth is just a simple AuthorizationAttribute:

```
public class UserAuthAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute {
    public int ProjectId { get;set;}
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase contextBase) {
        var currentProject=new Project(ProjectId);
        return currentProject.UserIsMember()
    }       
}
```

Now I want to use this with a parameter for the projectId. The following code **does not work** but should show what I want to achieve  (I cannot just add the id)

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
[UserAuth(ProjectId=id)]
public ActionResult Select(int id) {  
    return JsonGet(Magic.DoSomethingMagic());
}
```

Comment: Don't pass the id to `UserAuth`. Rather get it from the `Request` object. If you want the flexibility to either pass or not pass the id to `UserAuth`, then you can make the param nullable and if it's null, then you look for it in `Request`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to pass id from your AuthorizationAttribute. you can get it from request.

your action will look like

```
 [Route("{id:int}")]
        [UserAuth]
        public ActionResult Select(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And inside your attribute class, you can get route values.

```
public class UserAuthAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase contextBase)
        {
            var getRouteData =contextBase.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
            if(getRouteData != null)
            {
                ProjectId = Int32.Parse(getRouteData.ToString());
            }
            if(ProjectId > 5)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }           
        }
    }
```