# Exchange Properties between Actions in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes, httpcontext

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633488/use-attribute-routing-parameters-for-other-attributes) where the answer was that I do not need to do this at all. While this was correct for that approach this does not help me here.

I have the following Action:

```
[MyCaching]
[MyUserAuth]
public class MyMagicController:Controller {
   public ActionResult GetLoans() {
      return GetLoansForThisUser();
   }
}
```

`MyUserAuth` is an Attribute, which checks, if the User has the permissions to get the data. This information is retrieved from a DB and cannot be retrieved (purely) through the HttpContext. A few Users are Administrators who should see a bit more.

If the User has normal access (like 90% of the users) the Caching-Mechanisms in the `[MyCaching]` - Attribute should start and the content should be returned from Cache.

If it is an Administrator, the Cache should not be returned and not be filled, cause the content is different.

So I need to find a way for the `[MyUserAuth]` to tell the `[MyCaching]` that information. Is there a direct way to achieve this? 
If not, can I "misuse" the `HttpContext` for that? E.g.:

```
public class MyAuthAttribute:AuthenticationAttribute
    // ...
    public void CheckPermissions(HttpContext context) {
        context.Items.Add("isAdmin",true);
    }
}

public class MyCachingAttribute:ActionAttribute {
    // ...
    public void GetCache(HttpContext context) {
        if (context.Items["isAdmin"]) {
            return // dontcache;
        }
    }
}
```

And then put `MyUserAuth` just before `MyCaching`?

Comment: why can't you set a role/claim isAdmin on authentication? You could then check it in MyCaching

Answer (score 0):

You could set a role or a claim 'isAdmin' on authentication, which you could check in MyCaching, through the HttpContext